# NullPointerException when importing XML-file into Processing, Java

Tags: java, xml, class, oop, processing

I'm trying to get data from an XML-file and use this data in processing. When doing so I get a NPE, and I can't quite figure out where I'm wrong. The XML got several layers and I have to get data from this "child":

http://i62.tinypic.com/2mb90g.png

My code looks like this:

```
XML xml;

void setup(){

xml = loadXML("parker.xml");

XML[] children = xml.getChildren("kml");

XML[] Folder=children[0].getChildren("Folder");

XML[] Placemark=Folder[1].getChildren("Placemark");

XML[] Polygon=Placemark[2].getChildren("Polygon");

XML[] outerBoundaryIs=Polygon[3].getChildren("outerBoundaryIs");

XML[] LinearRing=outerBoundaryIs[4].getChildren("LinearRing");

  for (int i = 0; i < LinearRing.length; i++) {
    float coordinates = children[i].getFloat("coordinates");
    println(coordinates);

  }
}
```

Best Chris

Stack trace:

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content
>   is not allowed in prolog.     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
>     at processing.data.XML.(XML.java:187)     at
>   processing.core.PApplet.loadXML(PApplet.java:6310)    at
>   processing.core.PApplet.loadXML(PApplet.java:6300)    at
>   XMLtryout.setup(XMLtryout.java:21)    at
>   processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2359)     at
>   processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2254)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

XML file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xn3thjskhlf2wai/parker.xml

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: added to the post now

Comment: I think your xml is malformed.. Can you post it ?

Comment: Which XML API are you using? (not W3C DOM/SAX obviously)

Comment: XML-file added to the post.

Comment: @PeterWalser - I'm not quite sure what API means, sorry? I mean. I use Processing and therefore Java to visualize the data. Cheers Chris

Comment: API = Application Programming Interface. Your code refers to a class called 'XML', where does it come from (which package, framework, library)? The standard way in Java is to use a org.w3c.dom.Document to represent an XML document in memory, and since you are using something different it's important to know what excactly. Your stack trace answers it alredy: it's a custom class named 'processing.data.XML' which uses SAX to parse the XML.

Comment: Okay. So I guess this is a beginner's fault... I did not think about using an XML API. I think we have to get a library for parsing the XML document in processing. @PeterWalser - do you know any library (or something) that can do this for me?

Comment: DOM and SAX are already included in Java, here's some nice tutorials on how to use them: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

This error maybe caused because missing this at the top of your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

or there's some non-printable garbage at the start of your file.

Comment: Hmm. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> is written at the top of the xml file. So I guess thats not the problem. Could the "garbage" maybe be the HTML format in the start of the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The '*Content is not allowed in prolog*' error indicates that you have some content between the XML declaration and the appearance of the document element, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
content here is not allowed
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
...
</kml>
```

The XML file you linked is ok though, so it seems you're

- reading the XML binary incorrectly before passing it to the XML parser,
- or (more likely) **you're not reading the XML at all** (can happen when you read from a web URL and getting an error response). **I assume you get a HTTP 40x error which you don't recognize, and read the response (usually HTML) as XML, which causes the error.** Remember that applets usually can only read resources from the same server (that's what might cause the error).

To verify this, attempt to read the URL content and output it as text, and check if it looks ok.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do now, then? Should I delete the "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1"-URL in the XML file?

Chris

Comment: No, the XML-namespace is ok. As you have an Applet (according to your stack trace), how do you read the XML file? Can you post the code in your 'PApplet.loadXML'?

Comment: I have posted everything I have (in the code and in the stack trace). I was told by my teacher that Processing would be able to parce the XML file the way I did it already. So I think I need a library or something that could help me read the XML file? Chris

Comment: I don't know if it is the problem, but originally the XML file is a KML that I converted to XML. Could that be the problem?

Comment: As far as I can read it should be possible to call loadXML("filename.xml") from inside PApplet to read XML data in Processing.

Comment: The question is, how does the PApplet read the XML resource (Input Stream) based on the file name. You may try resolving the file's URL and pass its String representation to the readXML method: 
 URL url=getClass().getResource("parker.xml");
 String name = url.toExternalForm();
 loadXML(name);
To make sure the XML is found and can be read, you can check the URL and read from it directly with url.openStream().

Comment: Thanks Peter. I fixed the problem my self. I found out that my XML file had some BOMS that I had to erase which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make it more easy

try  like this

```
public static void setUp(){
    try {
  File file = new File("parker.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = db.parse(file);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("LinearRing");
  System.out.println("Information");

  for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

    Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

    if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

           Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
      NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("coordinates");
      Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
      NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("coordinates : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

      //

      //
    }

  }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

that should display :

```
Root element kml
Information
coordinates : 
              10.088512,56.154109,0
              10.088512,56.154109,0
              10.088512,56.154109,0
              10.088511,56.15411,0
              10.088511,56.15411,0
              10.08851,56.15411,0
              10.08851,56.154111,0
              10.088509,56.154111,0
              10.088508,56.154111,0
              10.088508,56.154111,0
              10.088507,56.154111,0
              10.088506,56.154111,0
              10.088506,56.154111,0
              10.088505,56.154111,0
              10.088504,56.154111,0
              10.088504,56.154111,0
              10.088503,56.15411,0
              10.088503,56.15411,0
              10.088502,56.15411,0
              10.088502,56.154109,0
              10.088502,56.154109,0
              10.088501,56.154109,0
              10.088501,56.154108,0
              10.088501,56.154108,0
              10.088501,56.154108,0
              10.088501,56.154107,0
              10.088285,56.154094,0
              10.088104,56.154372,0
              10.088061,56.154401,0
              10.087988,56.15445,0
              10.087915,56.154611,0
              10.08791,56.154613,0
              10.087912,56.154613,0
              10.087877,56.1548,0
              10.08772,56.15482,0
              10.087558,56.154911,0
              10.087421,56.155111,0
              10.087316,56.155308,0
              10.087328,56.15538,0
              10.087372,56.155413,0
              10.087446,56.155453,0
              10.087484,56.155487,0
              10.08747,56.155601,0
              10.08772,56.155616,0
              10.087719,56.155618,0
              10.088618,56.155671,0
              10.089096,56.1557,0
              10.089096,56.155699,0
              10.089138,56.155701,0
              10.089127,56.155706,0
              10.089004,56.155787,0
              10.08888,56.155853,0
              10.088799,56.155806,0
              10.088571,56.155914,0
              10.088455,56.155946,0
              10.088112,56.156081,0
              10.088184,56.156138,0
              10.087733,56.156353,0
              10.087489,56.156421,0
              10.087288,56.156341,0
              10.087268,56.156333,0
              10.086893,56.156182,0
              10.08684,56.156271,0
              10.087049,56.156373,0
              10.086893,56.156455,0
              10.086664,56.156575,0
              10.086443,56.156698,0
              10.086425,56.156708,0
              10.085983,56.156955,0
              10.085655,56.157139,0
              10.085462,56.157276,0
              10.085272,56.157233,0
              10.085176,56.157328,0
              10.084917,56.157393,0
              10.084883,56.157458,0
              10.08495,56.157513,0
              10.084947,56.157524,0
              10.084943,56.157539,0
              10.084855,56.15787,0
              10.084855,56.15787,0
              10.084321,56.157317,0
              10.085553,56.156195,0
              10.085555,56.156194,0
              10.085553,56.156194,0
              10.085734,56.156035,0
              10.085821,56.155977,0
              10.085937,56.155932,0
              10.085993,56.155942,0
              10.086031,56.155959,0
              10.086171,56.15592,0
              10.086227,56.155901,0
              10.086392,56.155841,0
              10.086513,56.155786,0
              10.08664,56.155699,0
              10.086686,56.155657,0
              10.086727,56.155605,0
              10.086777,56.155486,0
              10.086861,56.155289,0
              10.086916,56.155134,0
              10.087006,56.154899,0
              10.087075,56.154706,0
              10.087094,56.154649,0
              10.0871,56.154574,0
              10.087112,56.154464,0
              10.087111,56.154362,0
              10.087112,56.154279,0
              10.087112,56.154279,0
              10.087113,56.15427,0
              10.087114,56.154198,0
              10.087108,56.15413,0
              10.087091,56.154054,0
              10.086992,56.153698,0
              10.087,56.153678,0
              10.087031,56.153647,0
              10.087036,56.153648,0
              10.087046,56.153652,0
              10.087035,56.153647,0
              10.087039,56.153645,0
              10.087072,56.153612,0
              10.087367,56.153308,0
              10.087371,56.153303,0
              10.08742,56.15323,0
              10.087568,56.152963,0
              10.087568,56.152962,0
              10.087569,56.152962,0
              10.08757,56.152961,0
              10.087571,56.15296,0
              10.087573,56.152959,0
              10.087574,56.152959,0
              10.087575,56.152958,0
              10.087577,56.152958,0
              10.087579,56.152958,0
              10.087581,56.152957,0
              10.087582,56.152957,0
              10.087584,56.152957,0
              10.087586,56.152958,0
              10.087588,56.152958,0
              10.087589,56.152958,0
              10.087591,56.152959,0
              10.087592,56.152959,0
              10.087593,56.15296,0
              10.087594,56.152961,0
              10.087595,56.152962,0
              10.087596,56.152963,0
              10.087596,56.152964,0
              10.087596,56.152965,0
              10.087596,56.152965,0
              10.087614,56.152967,0
              10.087921,56.152988,0
              10.088134,56.153019,0
              10.088311,56.15304,0
              10.088454,56.153052,0
              10.088469,56.153378,0
              10.08847,56.153445,0
              10.088473,56.153597,0
              10.088473,56.153597,0
              10.088473,56.153597,0
              10.088703,56.153614,0
              10.088703,56.153614,0
              10.088703,56.153614,0
              10.088704,56.153614,0
              10.088705,56.153614,0
              10.088705,56.153615,0
              10.088706,56.153615,0
              10.088706,56.153615,0
              10.088707,56.153616,0
              10.088707,56.153616,0
              10.088707,56.153616,0
              10.088707,56.153617,0
              10.088707,56.153617,0
              10.088707,56.153617,0
              10.088707,56.153618,0
              10.088512,56.154108,0
              10.088512,56.154109,0

coordinates : 
              10.086779,56.155487,0
              10.086778,56.155488,0
              10.086779,56.155487,0
              10.086779,56.155487,0

coordinates : 
              10.08847,56.153602,0
              10.088469,56.153602,0
              10.088469,56.153602,0
              10.08847,56.153602,0
```

PS : kml is the root element